# Origin of Trigonometric Functions

Tags: trigonometry

How were functions like "sin", "cos" and "tan" originally developed? What were the motivations? Why were the ratios of certain lengths deemed important? Are there any proofs in geometry that show how these functions were originally formulated and defined?

Comment: The original development occurred, as far as we can tell, in ancient times. So your question is one of extreme historical difficulty. I would suggest looking up information about mathematics in ancient Babylonia and Egypt.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but I do not have enough reputation.

See https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/history-of-sine-function

and https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/discovery-of-sine-and-cosine/2152#2152

as starting points.